# How to highlight (and find) huge column numbers in minified JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, line-numbers

I got an error report for a minified JavaScript file which said that there was an error in line number 11 and column number 60757.

My question is now how to find column number 60757 in a minified JavaScript file which is just one huge line?

When I copy the file into Notepad++ (or any other editor) then there is not such a high column number as 60757. So how does JavaScript calculate the line and column numbers?

Because my editor says that the file has 15 lines and 460361 characters. So there must be a different calculation within the browser when that error occured.

Comment: Add a few hard returns into the source at syntactically correct locations?

Comment: this is exactly you don't want to debug with minified code. use the orig source so you can get meaningful direction from errors.

Comment: Imagine a file as a huge table with rows and columns. A row is a line, a column is where you place the chars. That means that your error is on line 11, on the char 60757.

Comment: Either debug using the unminified script, or use [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

Comment: This may help with Notepad++, Search -> Go to Line function, choosing the Offset radio button. From: http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/6a773f66

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Thanks for your answer. But if I open the File in Notepad++ and I move to line 11, then there are only 32080 chars in line 11 (and not 60757). Character 32081 is in line 12. So where does the browser do the line-breaks?

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer Probably there is an EOF problem. Or you were seeing the file length. There is an area, on the status bar on notepad++, which shows the column (it says the line you are in, the column or char you are, the selection length and the number of lines selected).

Answer (score 3):

If you do have source maps available for the minified JS, you can use [`sourcemap-lookup`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sourcemap-lookup) to manually find the corresponding position in the unminified JS:

```sh
# note that ./my-js.min.js.map should also exist
npx sourcemap-lookup ./my-js.min.js:11:60757
```

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you try unminifying the script and using that to debug?

http://unminify.com/

Comment: that would make a suitable comment

Comment: Yeah, only if it worked... Using this sample input: `i++;i<0&&console.log(33);` produces the same code. instead of `i=i+1; if(i<0){console.log(33);}`.

Comment: @Kroltan It really does! However it doesn't expend `i++` to `i=i+1`, but that isn't a problem (to those who are used to it, it makes no difference but it might be a game changer for someone who is starting with javascript).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I agree, but that at least is easily searchable, since it's a actual feature (unlike pseudo-`if`s abusing `&&`), I guess.

Comment: @Kroltan It isn't a 'pseudo-if', but rather a speedup and a 'minimification'. It works exactly the same, except that it only takes 2 bytes and takes advantage of the laziness in expression evaluation and probably a bit faster since it doesn't have to do any jumps on the assembly code. In my opinion, it is a cleaver technique but unreadable to the untrained eye. I agree about it not being easily searchable, but for that we have websites like http://stackoverflow.com . But you have a point, a really nice point on your comment.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I didn't mean to insult the technique, maybe my English knowledge was too limited for that, sorry. I just meant that it's a less readable way to execute code conditionally.

Comment: @Kroltan You didn't insult. But it really is less readable, but an improvement in speed (in my mind, in theory) and the code takes up less 2 bytes. This is something important to notice when minifying code. Or for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com